# Laravel Function/implementation to check the column in a DB or something similar all the time?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am wondering if there is a function that is always checking a column in a DB and it runs in the background.

For example:

```
if(date<Carbon::now())
{
  //change value in other column
}
```

That data flow but always checking the DB constantly. I think this can be done through events and listeners? But I am unsure.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean to say, You need to check the column in the table  and then insert?

Comment: No i meant to look at a column which has dates to check if it is `< Carbon::now()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [**Task Scheduling**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling).

First, add cron entries to your server :

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Then, create artisan command or a clousure from `app/Console/Kernel.php` :

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        // Your logic
    })
    ->everyMinute();
}
```

This will check for **every minute**. Of course you can change [schedule frequency options](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options).

If you need to compare date via [**Carbon**](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), you may use :

```
$now = Carbon::now();

if($entry->your_date_col->lessThan($now))
{
    // change value in other column
}
```

> Note : Don't forget to convert date mutator in your model. By default, Eloquent will convert the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns to instances of Carbon.

```
$protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on *what* you're using this data for, [an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) may be an easier approach:

```
public function getFooAttribute($value) {
    if($this->bar < Carbon::now()) {
        return 'some modified value';
    }

    return $value;
}
```

This won't change the value in the database, but it'll change the value in the model itself. If you're changing it just for display purposes, this'll do the trick with no changes to the underlying database storage.

Comment: (Side note: I don't remember if you can use `<` with Carbon object. You may need to use one of the [comparison functions](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) like `lessThan()` instead; adjust accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a cron job, which executes after every or after minutes, 5 as you require.

```
curl http://yourdomain.com/cron
```

Create a controller function in which you write the functionality.

```
if(date<Carbon::now())
 {
   //change value in other columns
 }
```